# How do I 301 redirect a bad incoming link such as www.site.com / or www.site.com/ <space after it

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have bad incoming links which webmaster tools shows, how do I fix the issue, I've tried all kinds of different 301 rewrites and redirects, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please tell us, what it is, you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect 'too short' URLs like `site.com/%20` (waste space) or `site.com/.` (waste dot) to the main page:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.{1,3}$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That fixed the space after the url like http://www.site.com/ <space after, but not the http://www.site.com / That one still is a 404 page.

Comment: what do you mean with `site.com /`? a space before `/`? that's actually not possible.